# Wicket - Move objects from one dataview to another

Tags: ajax, wicket, repeater, move, dataview

I am using Apache Wicket and...

1. I have a java class: task. There are active and finished tasks.
2. I have a sortable dataView for active tasks:

   ```
   final DataView<LongRunningTask> dataViewActive = new DataView<LongRunningTask>("sorting", dp) {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Override
       protected void populateItem(final Item<LongRunningTask> item) {
           LongRunningTask task = item.getModelObject();

           if(task.getRemainingTime() <= 0) {
               finishedTasks.add(item);
           }
               item.add(new Label("taskId", String.valueOf(task.getTask().getId()))); 
               item.add(new Label("startedBy", task.getTask().getUser()));
               item.add(new Label("characteristics", String.valueOf(task.getTask().getType() + " : " + task.getTask().getNoOfMessages()) + " : " + task.getTask().getTemplateFile())); 
               Label clock = new Label("timer", String.valueOf(task.getRemainingTime()));
               item.add(clock);
               clock.setOutputMarkupId(true);
               item.add(new ActionPanel("actions", item.getModel())); 

           }
   };
   ```
3. Now I want to create a dataview for FINISHED tasks. If the tasks are finished (Task.finished = true) then the task should be removed from the active dataview and added to the finished dataview.

   ```
   final DataView<LongRunningTask> dataViewFinished = new DataView<LongRunningTask>("sorting", dp) {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Override
       protected void populateItem(final Item<LongRunningTask> item) {
           LongRunningTask task = item.getModelObject();

           if(task.getRemainingTime() <= 0) {
               finishedTasks.add(item);
           }
               item.add(new Label("taskId", String.valueOf(task.getTask().getId()))); 
               item.add(new Label("startedBy", task.getTask().getUser()));
               item.add(new Label("characteristics", String.valueOf(task.getTask().getType() + " : " + task.getTask().getNoOfMessages()) + " : " + task.getTask().getTemplateFile())); 
               Label clock = new Label("timer","finished");
               item.add(clock);
               clock.setOutputMarkupId(true);
               item.add(new ActionPanel("actions", item.getModel())); 

           }
   };
   ```

How can I do that? I can create a 2nd dataview, but there were UI problems and conflicts. What is the best way?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the provider you are using for each of the dataviews is returning only the appropriate objects. That is all. As long as you keep the models filled with the appropriate lists of objects, the view will display them.

First, get rid of this from the actual populate method (remember this is the VIEW, you should only put view logic here, no business logic):

```
 if(task.getRemainingTime() <= 0) {
        finishedTasks.add(item);
 }
```

Second, implement you DataProvider so it only returns tasks that are either finished or not. You can pass a boolean in it's constructor or something like that. Pass two instance of the data provider to the two dataviews, one with boolean true, other false.

Comment: Yes. It works now. I used 2 seperate DataProviders. Lot of redundant code, maybe it can be done with one DataProvider. But for now its ok. Thanks

Comment: You can use the same class twice instantiated, with a parameter in it's constructor to select which ones to return. No redundancy that way.